# Access Javascript Array in C++/Plugin?

Tags: javascript, plugins, npapi, firebreath, jsctypes

I have written a NPAPI Plugin using firebreath framework. I am able to pass simple numeric values from Javascript and access them in my (C++)plugin, perform operations and then return the result. I would like to know how to operate on vectors now i.e arrays. I do not want to allocate new array inside my plugin and copy the array from JavaScript(Although I have no clue on how to do it). How can I directly access the JavaScript array in my plugin ? Is there a special way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Firebreath website](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Supported+JSAPI+types):

Javascript objects can be used with the FB::JSObjectPtr type. Examples of JavaScript objects that you may want to use include:

1. Javascript objects (with methods and/or value members)
2. Javascript Arrays (that you plan to modify; otherwise you can use a container type)
3. Javascript methods for callback

Arrays are objects; get values with getProperty(n) or getProperty("length") etc

You can also use methods like ->invoke("push", FB::variant_list_of(val)) etc

(on the JSAPI method in order to use the JSObjectPtr type you should use a method that looks something like:)

```
void doSomethingWithAnArray(const FB::JSObjectPtr& array) { ... }
```

Also remember that FireBreath can't tell what type of js object it is, just that there is a js object; you'll have to do your own error detection for the case where they don't give you an actual array but some other object instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot taxilian. I am even considering using js-ctypes(which apparently is much simpler). I know js-ctypes is mozilla specific and used in extensions. Do you see any difference i.e in what way one is better than the other ? I do not have any strict requirement on whether it should be extension or plugin. I just need to able to access native library.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, if something other than a plugin will do a job, do it that way. Plugins should not be used unless there are no other viable options for your application. That said, I've never used js-ctypes; I don't do extensions. The main downside is they lock you into a specific browser unless you write multiple versions.

Comment: Hi taxilian, I am trying to do it this way in firebreath. But it doesn't work. Can you please let me know what's wrong ?   ` void TestJSAPI::addvect(const FB::JSObjectPtr A, const FB::JSObjectPtr B,  FB::JSObjectPtr& C, int N){ int i = 0;
                  
 for(i = 0; i < N / 2; i++){
  std::cout << "Adding" << std::endl;
  double sum = A->GetProperty(i).cast<double>() + B->GetProperty(i).cast<double>();
  C->SetProperty(i,sum); 
  
 }}`

Comment: new questions should be ask as a new question, not in a difficult to read comment; most likely, though, you need to make those "const FB::JSObjectPtr&" (with the reference) not just const.  I can't read it well enough to guess what else it could be

Comment: OK. Sorry about that. I am posting a new detailed question right-away